# _id is sometimes missing in return results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using python ElasticSearch package and doing the following query:

```
{
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'filter': [
                {
                    'range': {
                        'timestamp': {'lte': 0}  # This will be replaced by the actual timestamp
                    }
                },
                {
                    'term': {
                        'has_flag': {
                            'value': False
                        },
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    'fields': ['_id', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'timestamp'],
    '_source': False,
    'size': 100
}
```

The document entry is created/updated using the following:

```
my_body = {...}  # Actual dictionary with mapped values

await es.index(
        index='my_index',
        id='my_unique_id',
        body=my_body,
        refresh='true', # true is OK to our usecase
    )
```

In the results (['hits']['hits']), for some documents I get the `_id` field under the `fields` section and some don't. How can this be explained? If I look at the actual documents (by returning source and not fields), I can't visibly see any difference between the ones that do return `_id` and the ones that don't.

Comment: You don't need to retrieve the `_id` field via the `fields` array as the `_id` field is returned in the metadata of each hit no matter what at the same level as the fields section

Comment: Right, after I saw this issue, that's what I did. I directly access the `_id` field. But just wanted to know why this is happening.

Comment: Which ES version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using the Docker container and using curl I get: "number" : "7.17.1", "lucene_version" : "8.11.1"